# expand grid system column when i click in a icon bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

I have an google maps in a tab with bootstrap, but the map become to small, so i want to change a bootstrap grid system when i click on fa icon, i want the first column torns to col-md-8, and the second column torn to col-md-4. 
thx,

here my code:

```
<h2 class="block-title">Mapas Brasil</h1>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-cptec">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1" role="tab">Condição Atual</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#menu2" role="tab">Aviso</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#menu3" role="tab">Temperaturas</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        <div class="tab-content">
            <div class="tab-pane active" id="menu1" role="tabpanel">
            <div id="map-canvas"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="menu2" role="tabpanel">Aviso</div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="menu3" role="tabpanel">Temperaturas</div>
    </div>
```

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified nav-cptec">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="d-flex align-items-center nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#menu-1" role="tab">Anánalise Sinótica</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="d-flex align-items-center nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#menu-2" role="tab">Imagens de Satélite</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="d-flex align-items-center nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#menu-3" role="tab">Vale do Paraíba</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane active" id="menu-1" role="tabpanel">
            <img src="/images/sinotica.png" alt="" class="img-fluid">
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="menu-2" role="tabpanel">Satélite</div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="menu-3" role="tabpanel">Vale</div>
    </div>
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/mE72FHG.png" alt="Faça sua analise sinótica" class="img-fluid top5" width="100%">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You'll need javascript... Have you at least tried something yet?

Comment: Obviously I'm going to need JavaScript, but my attempts were flawed =(

Comment: Show us what you attempted, we'll start from there...

Comment: $('#abrir').click(function() {
  $('#teste').removeClass('col-md-6').addClass('col-md-8 open');
  $('#teste2').removeClass('col-md-6').addClass('col-md-4');
});

Comment: with this code works, but i want to click out and return to col-md-6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('#abrir').click(function() {
    $('#teste').removeClass('col-md-6').addClass('col-md-8 open'); 
    $('#teste2').removeClass('col-md-6').addClass('col-md-4'); 
});

$('body').click(function(e){
    //Detect if click is outside #abrir AND is "open"
    if($(e.currentTarget).closest('#abrir').length==0 && $('#abrir').hasClass('open')){
        $('#teste').addClass('col-md-6').removeClass('col-md-8 open'); 
        $('#teste2').addClass('col-md-6').removeClass('col-md-4'); 
    }
});
```

This should do the trick. What you want is to reverse what you do on the click element. Put an event on the body, to listen for every click and inside this handler, see if the clicked element is inside or outside the targeted element to make sure we trigger accordingly.

You'll have to make sure that all click handlers on your page do not prevent event bubbling (it shouldn't, as it is bad practice) or else the click outside the element will not always be seen...

Answer (score 0):

i added this code and change the column to col-md-6 to col-md-4, but when i click out, dont turn back.
javascript its the same that you gave to me

my code:

```
<div class="row">
    <div id="teste" class="col-md-6">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-cptec">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1" role="tab">Condi&ccedil;&atilde;o Atual</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#menu2" role="tab">Aviso</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#menu3" role="tab">Temperaturas</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <div class="tab-content">
            <div class="tab-pane active" id="menu1" role="tabpanel">
                <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-right" aria-hidden="true" id="abrir"></i>
            <div id="map-canvas"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="menu2" role="tabpanel">Aviso</div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="menu3" role="tabpanel">Temperaturas</div>
    </div>
 </div>
```